# Where can I find the C# 5 language specification?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, language-specifications

C# 5.0 is out now since August 2012. Where can I find the specification? They've stopped doing ECMA specs, but how about MSDN?

Comment: Hmm. I was going to point to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), but it looks like it still leads to the 4.0 spec right now.

Comment: Nothing much anywhere about c# 5.0 but you can get some interesting facts here in this link though -  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113752/5-nice-things-to-have-in-C-5-0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was originally unavailable online but since June 2013 it is [available for download from Microsoft](https://ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm).

Comment: Is there a PDF version for it?

Comment: @AminM By now it is still available only for C# 3 and C# 5

Comment: The C# 6 specification (currently a draft) can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/).

Answer (score 66):

If you have Visual Studio 2012 installed, you will find specification somewhere there:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx
```

similar with VS2013:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx
```

VS2015:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx
```

Comment: Be aware that for me, the document says it's “C# Language Specification Version 4.0”, but it actually is spec for C# 5.0.

Comment: @AaronAnodide: by now it's also available online, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx

Comment: Correcting myself, the online version is not the same version you find installed with VS 2012 - even though the MSDN page makes it look like that.

Comment: @Zarat DO you know what are the differences?

Comment: @svick I believe the whole async/await syntax was missing (and the copyright dates differed), so the online version probably was C# 4 instead of C# 5. I've just checked it again though, and they seem to have updated it. Now I can't find any obvious differences between the online version and the copy with VS 2012 anymore.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a page about this. http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter1/Specifications.aspx

Comment: VS2015: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx