# Is the "C# Language Specifications" updated for C# 6.0 or 7.0 yet?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, c#-7.0

C# is already 7.0. But [C# Language Specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) is still for 5.0.

I realize the specifications is outdated when I couldn't find `GetValueOrDefault()` for a nullable type  in the document.

I wonder if the specification has been updated yet, at least for 6.0?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617711/where-can-i-find-the-c-sharp-language-specification-6-0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features#t=201704010058271350841

Comment: Note: you will never find `GetValueOrDefault()` in the specification, as that's [part of the CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx), not the C# specification.

Comment: @PeterDuniho do you mean that the programming language implemented by CLR is a strict superset of C#? or do you mean that `GetValueOrDefault()` is in the C# standard library (or the .Net C# library), but not in the C# language?

Comment: The CLR doesn't implement a language, so I can't mean that. There's no _"C# standard library"_, so I can't mean that. There is the .NET framework, and that's where `GetValueOrDefault()` is defined. That method has existed since .NET 2.0 (when generic types were introduced, including `Nullable<T>`), and it's not even mentioned in the most recent published specification (C# 5). It's simply not, nor ever is likely to be, a part of the language specification. It's in a completely different part of .NET.

Comment: @Peter then in C# 6.0, how can i achieve the same without having `GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)`?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,8b928034cfee7d43. Not really sure what you mean by "achieve the same", or why you'd find yourself _"without having `GetValueOrDefault()`"_, but the source code is there for anyone to review. You can base any alternate implementation on the example there (not that it's exactly rocket science or anything).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where Can I Find the C# Language Specification 6.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617711/where-can-i-find-the-c-sharp-language-specification-6-0)

Comment: This question isn't off-topic. It doesn't ask a recommendation for a book. It asks for the location and status of C#'s reference. That's a valid question. of concern to most C# developers. Given the *unofficial* status of the current reference, it's also something that can't be answered by 1-year old answers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Instead of creating yet another Question & Answer that will be outdated in 1 year, why not rather put related information in specific tag (C#-6, C#-7) info?

Answer (score 12):

[The current status is](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/64):

- Microsoft's officially released spec is indeed 5.0.
- [An unofficial version of the 6.0 spec exists](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/tree/master/spec).
- Work is being done to update the ECMA spec to 6.0 and 7.x. [ECMA has released its 5.0 spec in December 2017.](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

But those are just specifications of the C# language, they don't specify types and members that exist in the base class library (with some exceptions that are required for various language features). Until recently, each framework defined its library on its own, but now even that is standardized, though the [.Net Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library).

Answer (score 4):

I have not found any official language specifications for C# 6 and 7 on Microsoft or ECMA site, but here are few links.

While Microsoft's documentation for C# 6 and 7 at these links is succinct, the StackOverflow pages have lots of examples, details and cover gotchas.

**For C# 7**

[What's new in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7) on Microsoft website.

**For C# 6**

[What's New in C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6) on Microsoft website.

**For C# 5 and older versions**

If someone stumbles upon this question looking for C# version 5, 4 or 2 specifications, Jon Skeet at  [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx) 
page has put together a nice collection of all the specifications.

*P.S. I am intentionally pasting an image snapshot of his page (instead of contents in text format) so I don't take the traffic away from his page.*

[image]

Comment: *"I am intentionally pasting an image snapshot of his page (instead of contents in text format) so I don't take the traffic away from his page."* Isn't that why Al Gore created hyperlinks?

Comment: For the record, I have absolutely no problem with the links being included directly.